# Preventing focus change when left/right keys are pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I would like to prevent my program from changing the focused element when the left/right keys are pressed, as I need something else to happen when those are pressed. Right now, when the keys are pressed after clicking a certain button to load everything, the focus is set to a combobox next to that button, which prevents the keys from doing anything, instead changing the selected index of the combobox.

I have this code for when a key is pressed on the window:

```
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!PostTypeComboBox.IsFocused && !PredefinedSubsComboBox.IsFocused && !SortComboBox.IsFocused)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case System.Windows.Input.Key.Left:
                    e.Handled = false;
                    ViewModel.GoToPreviousPost();
                    PreviousImageButton.Focus();
                    break;

                case System.Windows.Input.Key.Right:
                    e.Handled = false;
                    ViewModel.GoToNextPost();
                    NextImageButton.Focus();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried with and without the following lines within the switch statements:

```
    e.handled = False;
    PreviousImageButton.Focus();
    NextImageButton.Focus();
```

But nothing I do seems to prevent the focus from changing, and the _ImageButton.Focus() do not change the focus, it still returns to the combobox.

Comment: have you messed with TabStop properties at all?

Comment: I guess you need to set e.Handled = true;

Comment: SystemOnline, that solved the problem! Thank you. Not sure why I didn't try that before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe doing

```
e.Handled = true;
```

will be enough